# Using forked Symfony bundle via composer fails

Tags: git, symfony, github, composer-php

I'm trying to install the [`hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle`](https://github.com/hslavich/SimplesamlphpBundle). As this bundle has dependency problems with `simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.2`, I [forked the repository](https://github.com/saxid/SimplesamlphpBundle) and require `dev-master` instead.

Now I modified my Symfony2's project `composer.json` accordingly, in order to require my forked bundle instead of the original one:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:saxid/SimplesamlphpBundle.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I still get the same error message as if no fork used:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.2 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.1 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.13.0 requires openid/php-openid dev-master#ee669c6a9d4d95b58ecd9b6945627276807694fb as 2.2.2 -> no matching package found.
    - hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp ~1.13 -> satisfiable by simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.13.2].
    - Installation request for hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle[dev-master].
```

What do I have to modify in my `composer.json` in order to require my fork?

Answer (score 1):

You need to lower your minimum stability from `stable` to `dev` in order to install unstable versions, like `dev-master`.

Change your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "hslavich/simplesamlphp-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:saxid/SimplesamlphpBundle.git"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

Also you need to enable `prefer-stable` to tell composer that you want stable packages when it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `composer.lock` file and the whole `vendor/` directory. Then run `composer update --prefer-source` to fully refresh the dependencies.

Comment: Can you post your full `composer.json` file?

Comment: It's the default Symfony composer file with added contents as mentioned in my question. No further modifications.

Answer (score 0):

A (pretty ugly) workaround is to submit the fork to [packagist](https://packagist.org/) and to directly require the fork instead of the original bundle.

Plus: I had to require the `dev-master` of `simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp` in my Symfony `composer.json` as well – although this requirement has already been defined in my forked bundle composer file.

```
"require": {
    ...
    "saxid/simplesamlphp-bundle": "dev-master",
    "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "dev-master"
},
```